# Self Learning PickList in Jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autofill

I have to populate a picklist which will have autocomplete feature and in case if the value is not there in picklist it will stil retain the value since it will be added in picklist & will be available for next time the user comes to the screen.Is there a plugin in jquery available to support these features?

Answer (score 0):

use `localStorage` to save this autocomplete, for example json encoded. At next call decode it and generate the list from the array.